# Error: undefined method `attach_resumes' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

I have user table I need user create a CV on `attach_resumes` table, I have create relationship but showing this error:

> undefined method `attach_resumes' for nil:NilClass

Below my code what I'm wrong?

user model

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :attach_resumes
end
```

attach_resumes model

```
class AttachResume < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

attach_resumes controller

```
 def new
  @attach_resume = AttachResume.new
 end

def create
  params.permit!
    if @attach_resume =  @user.attach_resumes.create(params[:attach_resume])
   flash[:notice] = "Attached Resume successfully"
   render "attachCV"
  else
    render "attachCV"
    flash[:warning] = "Please Attach Only PDF"
  end
end
```

Would be a great if anyone find solution

Comment: From the error code seems like your `@user` is `nil`. Can you verify the `@user` is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your `@user` is not verified

User verify process:

helper/applecation_helper

```
def user
  @user ||= User.find_by(user_id: session[:user_id])
end
```

& then use `@user`

Hope will understand this

Answer (score 3):

The model should be:

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :attach_resume
end
```

Notice that `:attach_resume` without `s`

So, when you create the `attach_resume` in the controller will be:

```
@user.create_attach_resume(params[:attach_resume])
```

Answer (score 0):

As it specifies, you are calling `attach_resumes` on a nil class. Check if @user contains any value at that part.

Also, on a side note:
You are establishing a one-to-one relationship but using the one-to-many pluralization in both model and controller. If you actually want to have one-to-one, change the line in your model to

```
has_one :attach_resume
```

and in your controller too

```
@user.attach_resume.create(params[:attach_resume])
```

If you want to have one-to-many, then update the relation to

```
has_many :attach_resumes
```

Answer (score 0):

Your association is wrong. It must be `has_one :attach_resume` because `has_one` is singular. So you must define `attach_resume` model as singular also.

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :attach_resume
end
```

You can refer associations [here for your situation.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) And you can refer [Active Record Association here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)